# Currency Layer API

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have got free membership from currency layer. I want to convert currency but its not allowed in free membership. Instead they provided me with a `LIVE API` where I can get current exchange rates. So I decided to make a way to use this live API for currency conversion by doing some tic tac with the jQuery code. I modified the code to some extent and I think I just nearly succeeded (maybe I am wrong). I have limited working knowledge of jQuery so I got stuck at the last point. Below are the codes with explanation to the issue.

API received from them

```
// set endpoint and your access key
endpoint = 'live'
access_key = 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY'; // can't reveal API key

// get the most recent exchange rates via the "live" endpoint:
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://apilayer.net/api/' + endpoint + '?access_key=' + access_key,   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {

        // exchange rata data is stored in json.quotes
        alert(json.quotes.USDGBP);

        // source currency is stored in json.source
        alert(json.source);

        // timestamp can be accessed in json.timestamp
        alert(json.timestamp);

    }
});
```

What I tried

```
// set endpoint and your access key
endpoint = 'live'
access_key = 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY';  // can't reveal API key

var from = $('#from').val();
var to = $('#to').val();
var combine = from+to;

// get the most recent exchange rates via the "live" endpoint:
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://apilayer.net/api/' + endpoint + '?access_key=' + access_key,   
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
    // exchange rata data is stored in json.quotes
    //var response = json.quotes.combine;
    alert(json.quotes.combine); // HERE IN PLACE OF USDGBP I USED THE COMBINE VARIABLE
    $('#convert').html('response');
}
});
```

`combine` variable used above is returning undefined. Maybe I did not code properly as I have limited jquery knowledge. If I can fix this then I will be able to use the code most probably. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access an object property via a variable holding its name you need to use bracket notation. To set the value of an `input`, use `val()`. Try this:

```
success: function(json) {
  var value = json.quotes[combine];
  $('#convert').val(value);
}
```

Comment: Working... and `#convert` is a form field here with ID convert. I need to place this result in that form field. Suppose I took `var response = json.quotes[combine];`. Now how to output that in the form field? My code above seems to be incorrect.

Comment: If the `#convert` element is an input you should use `val()` to set the value, eg: `$('#convert').val(response);`. I've updated the answer for you.

Comment: got it perfectly working as I wanted.. but I am wondering if there was a way to bypass the 1000 API request limit of the free membership..

Comment: If there is it will be illegal to use it. If you need to use that API, then pay the developer, exactly as you'd expect to be paid for something you've created.